# rem get unexpected px when meta scale 0.5 (only in chrome simulator)

Tags: css, scale, simulator, meta

Simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="font-size: 100px;">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
<style>
p{
    font-size: 0.2rem;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex..doindex.doindex.fsadfa1234</p>
</body>
</html>
```

chrome calc 0.2rem to 33.2px.

Console screenshot:

[image: screenshot console]

Comment: what value is expected?

Comment: @Aziz The OP has 100px for a rem size, so 0.2 of that would be 20px.

Comment: @user2926630 I see you're emulating an iPhone 5. Yes, if I do that, I get 33.2px too. With most other devices, it says 20px though, so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: @MrLister so, that's a chrome emulation bug?

Comment: @user2926630 Not sure if it's a chrome bug or an iphone bug! Maybe the iphone has some properties that causes the size to come out as that value under those circumstances. If you set the initial scale to 1, the font size will be 20px as expected.

Comment: @MrLister yes, no matter what scale is, it works good on my device

Comment: I'm just curious why would you use `scale=0.5`?